# How do I resolve DNS using Tor?

Tags: dns

I don't want my traffic to be proxied though Tor, but I want to anonymize DNS requests. How do I use Tor as a DNS server?

Answer (score 4):

Use `DNSPort 53` setting in `torrc` and configure nameserver to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more information to this (and to provide a source for others), an in-depth set of instructions and alternative solutions can be found in the below wiki entry.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tor#Using_TorDNS_for_all_DNS_queries

Answer (score 1):

Actually [the answer of @RichardHorrocks](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/7216/14629) is quite helpful, but IMHO leaves out some of the [relevant parts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tor#TorDNS):

- If you want to resolve a single hostname via Tor, use `tor-resolve $hostname` and for reverse (PTR) lookups use `tor-resolve -x $ip`. (For me, that part was relevant but nowhere else in this Q&A mentioned, hence the new reply.)

  Only drawback so far: You can't specify the query type (e.g. A, NS, MX, etc.) and also IPv6-only hosts (those with only AAAA records) can't (yet) be resolved at all and cause such a message: `[warn] Got SOCKS5 status response '4': host is unreachable`
- For using Tor to generally resolve all DNS requests of the local system, [the anonymous answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/7213/14629) already shows the basics and the link in the answer of @RichardHorrocks the details.