# How to only use Tor to resolve DNS queries

Tags: dns

I use want to anonymize my DNS requests ;
I've tried to put `DNSPort 53` in `torrc`, restarting the tor daemon and polipo, even restarting my computer.
By using `nestat -atop` I can't see any daemon listening on the port 53, however tor-resolve work well.

Using `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, I can't load any page

Comment: Related : https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/how-do-i-resolve-dns-using-tor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-a**t**op", the t stands for TCP.

Tor's DNSPort is UDP. Try `ss -uln`. It's also not a full DNS implementation and it only handles `A`, `AAAA` and `PTR` lookups.

Comment: Indeed, nice idea to exflitrate data using udp nobody look at it, use "update-rc.d tor enable" to put Tor at startup, put "nameserver 127.0.0.1" in your resolv.conf file and "DNSPort 53" in torrc, ipleak.net don't detect my DNS server anymore, CLOUDFLARE COLLECT DATA FOR CIA